# Merging Images To PDF in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I want to create an app which asks the user to upload the pictures from the device camera and then merge those images as PDF using **swift**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: 2 mins of R&D can answer this question. Please try to search on internet before posting new question.

Comment: @MayankJain thanks for your advice..i am new to swift programming and already did R&D on this and then only posted the question  !!!!

Comment: Didn't you find anything ?? I guess lots of people already asked this question here even in swift also. To maintain the post quality of SO, duplicate question should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @MayankModi It's really a pain to work with printing / PDF on macOS. There aren't many good libraries even now a year later. On iOS it's really easy, so I guess macOS devs were really lazy when they built the system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read your question and I have an idea for merging images to PDF.

Step 1: You need convert image to PDF. You can see the link below

https://github.com/SSA111/SwiftImageToPDFConverter/blob/master/NSData%2BImageToPDFConverter.swift

Step 2: Merge all files pdf